# How to combine strings in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

`foo.errors.full_messages` - How do I format all `foo` specific error messages to be combined into something `space` or `newline separated`

Comment: wow, its just amazing that folks don't find this question constructive. I have a question and there is a community who is willingly answering this question. The purpose of this community is solved here and its just weird that the moderators just pitch in and mark it as not constructive. feels like high handedness to me :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like it is actually a rails question? You can do `foo.errors.full_messages.join("\n")` for a newline or with `(" ")` for a space.

But better, try `foo.errors.full_messages.to_sentence` if this is indeed rails.

Answer (score 4):

It what you are looking for?

```
big_error_message = foo.errors.full_messages.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

object.errors.full_messages is a array of Strings.

You just need to use the [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) function as

```
foo.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
# or
foo.errors.full_messages.join(' ')
# etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just to show error messages on UI, try

```
<ul>
  <% model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It will show error in unordered list and you can  style `ul/li` as per your need